# Looking for the Control List Window of NetBeans GUI Builder

Tags: user-interface, netbeans

There was a window listing all Swing controls at the left bottom of NetBeans window. I guess I closed it for some reason. And now I cannot find it anymore. Anyone knows what the name of that window is and how to open it?

Comment: it is Inspector. Just let latters know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window is called the 'Inspector'.  You can open it using the Navigating->Inspector item of the Window menu.